# JSON.parse only parses parent object of string javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to parse a string in javascript from rails into a javascript object,

```
{"monday":"{\"open\"=\u003e\"10:30\", \"close\"=\u003e\"24:00\"}"}
```

However after calling `JSON.parse` on it I'm returned with

```
Object {monday: "{"open"=>"10:30", "close"=>"24:00"}"}
```

How Can I make it parse not just the initial object, but it's child objects as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no child objects. The value of the `"monday"` key is a string, not an object. That is, if you expect subobjects, check the code generating the JSON, since it is wrong. The correct JSON for your use case would be:

```
{"monday":{"open":"10:30","close":"24:00"}}
```

While you could, obviously, get around this and parse this as it is, it would be like calling in a wrecking ball operator to punch you a new hole in your living room wall when you can't find your front door key.

Comment: `{"monday"=>"{\"open\"=>\"11:30\", \"close\"=>\"12:45\"}"}` is the hash I'm gettings I'm using an Hstore field in rails and using a `store_accessor` to declare monday a field, then in my forms i use
`= f.fields_for :monday` with `text_fields` for open and close, yet that is the format i get, what can i do to fix this